# Conditionally loop over dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to perform the same operation on three dataframes -- except if the dataframe is called economy, I also need to add a column.

```
dframes_dict = {'economy': economy, 'finance': finance, 'language': language}
for x, df in dframes_dict.items():
     ...
    if df==economy:
#   if x == "economy"
       df['adding_column_to_economy_dataframe'] = "added"
    df.to_csv(f"df_{x}.csv")
```

How do I add the if statement in the loop?

Comment: What's the result of your code? It seems OK to me

Comment: ```if df==economy can't work``` because print(df) shows the whole output, not the name of the df. The error I get is: ```"truth value  of a dataframe is ambiguous"```

Comment: commented solution is correct, need `if x == "economy"`:

Comment: @jezrael that should work, although I suppose asd wanted to check the equality of the DataFrame objects themselves

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, I thought that wasn't giving me the exact result I expected or doubting myself. But  I was mistaken. Thanks again.

Comment: This workaround should help if you want to compare the dataframes `len(df[df.eq(economy).all(axis=1)==False])==0` , see https://towardsdatascience.com/comparing-pandas-dataframes-to-one-another-c26853d7dda7 for reference